# Is the process running in real time

Tags: c#

Is it possible to track the process in real time?
For example, I have an application that is associated with the game. If the game is running, the button works, if the game is closed, the button waits for the game to start.
How can this be implemented?
I found this code, but mine is not very good :)

```
while (true)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = 
     System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
     if (procs.Count() == 0)
          break;
}
```

Comment: Create a parent-child relationship. The parent process has a form with a button, and it launches the child process when the button is clicked. Then, the parent process can easily keep track of the child process, waiting for it to terminate. When the child process terminates, re-enable the button.

Comment: No, it won't work that way. I don't need to start the process. It may already be running by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code piece you have included works but it is very resource intensive, and it also blocks executing thread. You can use Timer events to check process status.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
myTimer.Interval = 1000; // 1000 ms is one second
myTimer.Start();

public static void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = 
         System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

     //isButtonEnabled is needed to be defined on the upper context
     isButtonEnabled = procs.Count() != 0

}
```

Comment: Great... Thank u.